How is it possible to replace characters step by step in Series?
There is a cell that contains multiple answer.



six_que




"Participation in environmental actions; caring for nature conservation";" Mentoring; transfer of experience; education of children / younger generation of youth"



I need to replace everything and leave only ";" to split the answer further.
I've tried to make several changes step by step, but the second step repeats and ";" is replaced by ",".
data['six_que'] = data['six_que'].str.replace(';', ',')
data['six_que'].str.replace('","', ';')
data['six_que'].str.replace('"', '')

What I get now:

Participation in environmental actions, caring for nature conservation, Mentoring, transfer of experience, education of children / younger generation of youth

What I want to get:

Participation in environmental actions, caring for nature conservation; Mentoring, transfer of experience, education of children / younger generation of youth

So, how to make several replacements and not to change the previous result.

Can you provide a DataFrame constructor for your input? Do you have a string?

IIUC, you can use a regex with a lookbehind:
df['six_que'] = df['six_que'].str.replace('(?<!");', ',', regex=True)

Output string:
"Participation in environmental actions, caring for nature conservation";" Mentoring, transfer of experience, education of children / younger generation of youth"

To also remove the quotes, chain with a second replace: df['six_que'].str.replace('(?<!");', ',', regex=True).str.replace(' *" *', '', regex=True).
Note that could also split directly on the ; that is surrounded by ":
df['six_que'].str.split('(?<=");(?=")')

Output:
['"Participation in environmental actions; caring for nature conservation"',
 '" Mentoring; transfer of experience; education of children / younger generation of youth"']

using CSV
Since your string looks a lot like CSV, a robust approach to split the string could be to use the csv module. The advantage is that the parsing will be robust, it will automatically handle escape characters/quotes, spaces, delimiters:
import csv

df['chunks'] = df['six_que'].apply(lambda s: next(csv.reader([s], delimiter=';',
                                   quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL), None))

Output for the first string:
['Participation in environmental actions; caring for nature conservation',
 'Mentoring; transfer of experience; education of children / younger generation of youth']


Thank you for the answer, but if replace all the characters with ',' , then I won't be able to split string with '";"'.

@DaniilLokutnikov you don't replace all ; with ,, just those that are not delimiters. Also what is your ultimate goal? If it to obtain a list of chunks from the original string then I strongly advise to use robust methods. A CSV parsing library is probably the best tool here. Please clarify the ultimate goal and the exact expected output in your question.

How about something like this:
mydata = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "six_que": [
            'Participation in environmental actions; caring for nature conservation";" Mentoring; transfer of experience; education of children / younger generation of youth',
            'another example";" using similar logic; just to check if it really works.',
        ]
    }
)

mydata["six_que"] = mydata["six_que"].str.replace(";", ",").str.replace('","', ";")

mydata["six_que"][0]
# 'Participation in environmental actions, caring for nature conservation; Mentoring, transfer of experience, education of children / younger generation of youth'

mydata["six_que"][1]
# 'another example; using similar logic, just to check if it really works.'

